# Real time event handler in ZKemKeeper library stop responding to device activity after some time

Tags: c#

I have created a simple Windows Service project to capture real time event from a fingerprint device using ZKemKeeper library. The service seems to work normally at the first time, and it responds well to the events in the device. But I found that, the service stop responding to the event after couple minutes of inactivity. I thought it was the service that caused the problem, but then the problem still there in WinForm application and even the samples included within the SDK showing the exact problem.

Here's the code for Windows Service:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;
    CZKEMClass myCZKEMClass;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();


        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
        this.eventLog1.Log = "MyLog";
        this.eventLog1.Source = "MyLogSource";

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();

        this.ServiceName = "ZKemKeeperTestService";


    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myCZKEMClass = new CZKEMClass();

        Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            myCZKEMClass.Connect_Net("192.168.1.20", 4370);


            if (myCZKEMClass.RegEvent(1, 65535))
            {
                myCZKEMClass.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(myCZKEMClass_OnAttTransactionEx);
            }

            Application.Run();
        });
        createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();

        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started");

    }


    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Stopped");
        myCZKEMClass.OnAttTransactionEx -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(myCZKEMClass_OnAttTransactionEx);

    }

    private void myCZKEMClass_OnAttTransactionEx(string EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerificationMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second, int WorkCode)
    {

        eventLog1.WriteEntry(EnrollNumber.ToString());

    }
}
```

I have no idea what's the cause of the problem and I'm stuck in there. FYI, I'm using the 64bit version of the library running in Windows 10. I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 as a target framework.

Achmad Mulyadi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same problem with you, please try to unregister the event than register again every 60 seconds, this work for me. I'm using 64bit version og the library running in windows 8.1

```
        if (bIsConnected == true)
        {
            this.axCZKEM1.OnFinger -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);

            iMachineNumber = 1;//In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
            if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            {
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think that code will work in winform, I'm not sure in Win Service tho, since I avoid to use timer in it. Btw what device did you use? I mean the brand and series? Seems it only happens in few devices. Just bought a new one last week and it works like charm even without re-registering the event, in both winform and windows service.

Answer (score 1):

if you still not find the answer make Timer and put this code inside it

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

This  will make the ActiveX to work

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add this code in the thread.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
{
    string IPAddr = null;
    if (axCZKEM1.GetDeviceIP(iMachineNumber, IPAddr))
    {
        LogHelper.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "device " + IPAddr + ":" + port + " connect status is ok.");
    }
});
timer.Interval = 600000;// 10 minutes
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking every where for solution reading the manual multiple times I found that my issue was the firewall so try disabling firewall or add exception to your software